# windows.print() stopped working in chrome after recent chrome update

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-chrome

A .net print page that used to render correctly on chrome for a long time is not doing so any more. This problem started after we noticed a series of chrome updates recently. The text appears overlapped. The print preview and the print renders fine on edge. The function used is windows.print(). Has anyone been able to resolve it.

Comment: It seems that this exact same question was asked recently.

Comment: It seems to me that if one is aware that a _problem started after we noticed a series of chrome updates recently_ and one wished to resolve this problem, that one would start by rolling back the updates.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.